# Paperclip question update/change image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip

Excuse me I am using paperclip. so when i attachment a file diferent to image (when i don´t upload jpeg,gif or png example zip) show this error:

```
* Photo C:/Users/MAXIMI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/stream4556-0.rar is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
* Photo C:/Users/MAXIMI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/stream4556-0.rar is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
* Photo C:/Users/MAXIMI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/stream4556-0.rar is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

which is the locale tree path for this error? or which are the locale tree path for paperclip error.

NOTE: I am talking about i18n locale (translate)

thanks in advance

Comment: Excuse if you need more information comment this post.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996102/rails-paperclip-and-passenger-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command) out

Comment: thanks. However i search locale (I18n)

Comment: First, that error comes from ImageMagick, not Paperclip. Second, you're uploading RAR files to an image processor, why? Third, Pizzicato's link points to the correct answer.

Comment: @jenjen Users do weird things - it's hardly uncommon to test for edge cases of unexpected user interaction.  That's like saying "Why did you try entering words into the phone field?  users won't do that!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the i18n translation path for this, but if you don't want users to upload non-image file types you should use the `validates_attachment_content_type` validator that paperclip gives you:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, /^image.*/, :message => "Your error message"
```

Which will generate a sane error for the user instead of the cryptic ImageMagick one.  Alternatively, if you want users to be able to upload any file type, but style images a certain way, you can fix your problem like this:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => {:thumbnail => ["89x67!", :jpg]}
before_post_process :image?

def image?
  !!(attachment_content_type =~ /^image.*/)
end
```

This will make it so that all images that get uploaded will also generate an 89x67 sized thumbnail, but if it's not an image type it will *skip* the processing because `image?` will return false, and the `post_process` will not execute (but the file will still be uploaded).

This adds the benefit of being able to say `asset.image?` later on in a view or something and deciding whether to render it within an image_tag, or as a direct link (just for example).

Comment: what is the /^image.*/ parameter?

Comment: excuse me, the validator of paperclip work but the continue showing the imageMagick error

Comment: Thanks. Now i test your solution. this is very good. I don´t know about before_post_process. Again Thank you.

Comment: @maxiperez that parameter can either be an array, or a single value of allowed content types.  Each value can be either a regular expression, or an exact-match string (in this case I chose regular expression to match for image filetypes).  Documentation for it is here:  http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods#validates_attachment_content_type-instance_method -- Also, I'm glad you were able to figure it out :)